# How to add tabs to UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I still new to iphone app. dev. , I create navigation based application , with uiNavigationController , the problem is when i selected nav controller and set the bottom bar to tabs there is no tabs appear , also when i add uitabcontroller there is no tab appear .

How to add tabs to UINavigationController using mainwindow.xib ? links , tutorials or any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code for creating a tabBarController with two controllers as tabs:

```
myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NewsFeedController * newsFeedController = [[NewsFeedController alloc] initWithFacebook:facebook];
UINavigationController * navigationControllerHome = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newsFeedController];
[newsFeedController release];
AboutController * aboutController = [[AboutController alloc] init];
UINavigationController * navigationControllerAbout = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutController];
[aboutController release];
myTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationControllerHome, navigationControllerAbout, nil];
[self.window addSubview:myTabBarController.view];
```